# Re-attach SQL database to replace the original (instead of backup/restore)

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a SQL 2012 database on Windows Server 2008R2 that has been detached by our infrastructure team as a form of backup.  We now need to restore the database, and there are no "proper" backups of the database.  I imagine we would need to do something like this:

1. Take the current Live DB offline
2. Delete the current DB from the file system
3. File copy the previously detached DB from its backed up location, into the \Data folder
4. Re-attach the DB

When copying, we would copy both the .MDF and .LDF files into the original \Data location.

Am I missing anything?

(Comments are also welcome on the advisability or otherwise of using "detach" as a backup method.)

Comment: That should do it.  Detaching as a form of backup is a wee bit, um, over-enthusiastic since the database is essentially non-existent during that time.  SQL Server's backup (or other third party backup tools) do the job and allow your database to remain active and usable.  That's what they're built for.

Comment: And after that I would strongly suggest you get not just a backup plan in place but also a restore plan in place. What I mean by that is many shops get in this situation and then start making backups. But they don't test those backups and understand how to restore the data in case of emergency. A backup plan is only the first step in data recovery.

Comment: Thanks.  As far as backups go, we used to script proper backups to disk, then these were in turn backed up by the infrastructure team, but they advised us that with their new SQL aware backup software we would no longer need to do that.

Comment: And that is proof of my previous comment. Where this failed is that nobody actually tested recovery.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to attach a database you need to consider the following prerequisites:

1. The database must first be detached. Attempting to attach a database that has not been detached will return an error
2. When you attach a database, all data files (MDF and LDF files) must be available. If any data file has a different path from when the database was first created or last attached, you must specify the current path of the file
3. When you attach a database, if MDF and LDF files are located in different directories and one of the paths includes \?\GlobalRoot, the operation will fail.

If there is nothing important to consider in prerequesties, then you can detach/attach the databases using following steps:

1. Detach the current database

> ```
> USE master;   
> GO   
> EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks2012'; 
> GO
> ```

2. Copy the desired database files to their location
3. Attach the database

> ```
> USE master;  
> GO  
> CREATE DATABASE YourDBName
>     ON (FILENAME = 'location to mdf file\YourDBName.mdf'),  
>     (FILENAME = 'location to ldf file\YourDBName.ldf')  
>     FOR ATTACH;  
> GO
> ```

Note that you might need to include your .ndf files in the above query, if they also exists.

You can do the following steps using SQL Server Management Studio detach/atach wizards too.

Finally using detach/attach is not a good solution for backup and recovery. You might read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database#Recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

you can detach your database using these T-SQL sentences:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'stellar'
GO
```

In order to attach, you can use the following T-SQL sentences:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [stellar] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\stellar.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\stellar_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Another way to attach a database is to use the create database

```
CREATE DATABASE Stellar  
ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\stellar.mdf')  
FOR ATTACH ;
```

If you do not have a log file, you can use the following T-SQL commands to generate a new log file:

```
CREATE DATABASE Stellar
ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\stellar.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG ;
```

Check reference [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31591/How-to-Attach-SQL-Database-Which-is-Not-Properly-Detached.html).